# How to create a Seq from an enumeration

Tags: scala, playframework, sequence

I have an enumeration that looks like:

```
object ContentType extends Enumeration {
  type ContentType = Value
  val BlogPost, KB, Link = Value
}
```

Now I want to create a dropdown list using this enumeration.

```
@helper.select(field = ContentForm("contentType"), options = @contentTypes)
```

Play has a `@helper.select` method that requires a Sequence, so I have added a sequence that I will pass to my view page:

```
val contentTypes: Seq[(Int, String)] = ...
```

How can I initialize or create this sequence from my ContentType enumeration?

**Update**

Sorry it has to be of type Seq[(String, String)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear to me why your `val contentTypes` has type `Seq[(Int, String)]`, maybe I'm missing something, but you can transform the `Enumeration` to a `Seq` so:

```
scala> object ContentType extends Enumeration {
 |     type ContentType = Value
 |     val BlogPost, KB, Link = Value
 |   }
 defined module ContentType

scala> ContentType.values.toSeq
res0: Seq[ContentType.Value] = ArrayBuffer(BlogPost, KB, Link)
```

Edit:

From @Marth comment, use `zipWithIndex` and `swap`:

```
scala> ContentType.values.toSeq.map(_.toString).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
res5: Seq[(Int, String)] = ArrayBuffer((0,BlogPost), (1,KB), (2,Link))
```

If you want `Seq[(String, String)]`:

```
scala>  ContentType.values.toSeq.map(_.toString).zipWithIndex.map(tuple => (tuple._2.toString, tuple._1))
res6: Seq[(String, String)] = ArrayBuffer((0,BlogPost), (1,KB), (2,Link))
```

**Step by step:**

```
ContentType.values.toSeq
```

Returns a `Seq[ContentType.Value]`, then calling `.map(_.toString)` returns a `Seq[String]`, you want now to have each `String` associated with a numeric identifier, we use the index of each value, `zipWithIndex` creates a `Seq` of tuples where the first value is the `String` and the second value is the index the String is at:

```
scala> ContentType.values.toSeq.map(_.toString).zipWithIndex
res7: Seq[(String, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((BlogPost,0), (KB,1), (Link,2)
```

We are quite there, the desired type is a `Seq[(String, String)]` where we have a `Seq[(String, Int)]`, note also that I supposed you wanted the tuples to be of type `(index, value)` while we have now `(value, index)`, so we map again for two reason, first to swap the values and second to transform the indexes to strings:

```
scala>  ContentType.values.toSeq.map(_.toString).zipWithIndex.map(tuple => (tuple._2.toString, tuple._1))
res8: Seq[(String, String)] = ArrayBuffer((0,BlogPost), (1,KB), (2,Link))
```

We could also shorten the code removing the first map which transforms our custom type to a string and delaying the `toString`invocation in the last map, having something like:

```
scala> ContentType.values.toSeq.zipWithIndex.map(tuple => (tuple._2.toString, tuple._1.toString))
res9: Seq[(String, String)] = ArrayBuffer((0,BlogPost), (1,KB), (2,Link))
```

Comment: When the form posts back, I want to use the Int value, and to display I need to use a String for the dropdownlist.

Comment: You could use `ContentType.values.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)`.

Comment: I see now, @Marth was faster, using `zipWithIndex` and swapping the values in the map is the way to go.

Comment: When I do:  val  a = ContentType.values.toSeq.map(_.toString).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap) I get a type of Seq[(Int, Any)].  I have to be explicit when defining my val then it works fine.

Comment: sorry, turns out it has to be: Seq[(String, String)]

Comment: For the wrong type inferring I can't tell you much, the code you see in my answer comes from the scala REPL v 2.11. I made an edit to the code, now the type is `Seq[(String, String)]`.

Comment: If you have time, can you explain what is going on in each step?  ContentType.values.toSeq.map(_.toString).zipWithIndex.map(tuple => (tuple._2.toString, tuple._1))

Comment: Great thanks!  Just to confirm, is this using the index from the enumeration or a automatically incrementing index creating by the zipWithIndex call?  b/c the enumeration index value may change.

Comment: No, it's using the index from the `Seq` which has 3 elements and so `0 -> BlogPost, 1 -> KB, 2 -> Link`, `zipWithIndex` simply transform what you have in a tuple of type `(value, index)`.